# Get objects outside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a bit of a complex mix of objects and arrays and I was looking for way to flatten the arrays so it's less complex when I try to render it.

Basically I have some input fields and there's an option to add custom fields with custom label and value, but the way it's stored in DB the label is `customLabel` and the value is the array of all the custom fields that were added

```
    const keyTerms = [
    {label: 'pre-set label', value: 'some value'},
    {label: 'pre-set label', value: 'some value'},
    {label: 'customLabel', value: [{}, {}]}
    ];
```

In my React component I'm mapping through that array to display the objects, but when I hit the object that has an array as a value, I get an error since the component is expecting an string instead of an array

```
    {keyTerms.map(keyTerm => <Component keyTerm={KeyTerm} />}
```

Inside the Component I tried to check if keyTerm.value is an array to map through it

```
Array.isArray(keyTerm.value)
? keyTerm.value.map(ele => (
   <>
     <Label>{keyTerm.label}</Label>
     <Description>{keyTerm.value}</Description>
   </>
))
: (
   <>
     <Label>{keyTerm.label}</Label>
     <Description>{keyTerm.value}</Description>
   </>
)
```

But that solution didn't work, it's passing the first check and always going to the else block then throwing this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {label, description, __typename}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Is there a way to take the objects from inside the third object value array and put them in the outside array?

Comment: What would you want the render result to be in the case of an array?

Comment: Make sure to use key by the way

Comment: Also, more info is needed here. Explain what you are trying to do a bit more. Why can the value be array of objects or string. And, what is Component doing with keyTerm?

Comment: @CertainPerformance The Component is like this:
```
<Label>{keyTerm.label}</Label>
<Description>{keyTerm.value}</Description>
```
in case of an array, I was trying to check: Array.isArray(keyTerm.value) then map through it and render the code above inside the map, else render the code above without the map

Comment: @TarekAlBeb that should work

Comment: @NathanHall I just modified the listing with some additional explanations for what I was trying to do and what I need to accomplish. Thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below: (however it may be worth it to create a reusable component out of the label/description fields so it’s not duplicated)

```
Array.isArray(keyTerm.value)
? keyTerm.value.map(ele => (
   <>
     <Label>{ele.label}</Label>
     <Description>{ele.value}</Description>
   </>
))
: (
   <>
     <Label>{keyTerm.label}</Label>
     <Description>{keyTerm.value}</Description>
   </>
)
```